# QGIS - Adding Raster Data to a Scanned Map

Tags: qgis

I'm a bit of a novice to QGIS, so apologies if this is a silly question:

I've scanned a geological map into QGIS, which shows different types of rock in different colours. It's a raster layer, and I'd like to have it work like the elevation layer I've imported from the USGS - that is, for each pixel to have a value (for example, 'chalk') so that I can then tabulate the type of rock on which various features are situated. How do I go about this?

Comment: It's very difficult with scanned maps, because it's very unlikely that, for example, all of the pixels in the 'chalk' areas will have identical values. You can spend an awful lot of time trying to do what you propose. It might be quicker to trace the geology objects to vector polygons. N.

Answer (score 1):

Raster cells can only contain numerical values. You have to check which colour correspond to a ceratin rock value. Depending on the kind of scanning, you either have three band RGB colours, or paletted one band.

You can use the raster calculator to get one new cell value from RGB, or take the paletted values directly.

You can use a categorized style to get the text values into the table of content.

Comment: Thanks - so how do I actually assign those numerical values to each colour? I've actually gone through by hand and turned each scanned colour into a single actual colour in GIMP.

Comment: If you save in GIMP as paletted, you already have one value for each rock type. If you have saved as RGB, you need the raster calculator to make one new value out of the R, G and B channel for a certain colour. You may need one condition for each rock type.